# How to get UIScrollView contentOffset during an animation

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, core-animation

I am trying to get the contentOffset property of a UIScrollView in the middle of a setContentOffset animation. Note I am not using the animated property of the method, but instead enclosing the setContentOffset operation within a UIView animation block so I can have finer control.

When I try to read the value of contentOffset in the middle of the animation, it returns the final value rather than the value at that moment. I know that you can use the presentationLayer to get the current layer, but is there any way you can get the current offset in the middle of an animation?

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve? If you're finding it difficult to determine the offset, you may be taking the wrong approach to the larger problem.

Answer (score 17):

Took me a while to figure this out too.  Try.........

```
CGPoint offset = [myScroll.layer.presentationLayer bounds].origin
```

Ray

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 5**

```
scrollview.layer.presentation()?.bounds.origin
```